# Permission for changing the title of a paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission, communication

I am revising a paper and want to change the title of the paper and send for editor-in-chief.

*My Question:* Is there an formal sentences to announce to editor-in-chief and reviewers that I want to change the title of paper in this revision.

For instance, is it acceptable that I write the following text?

> With the editor-in-chief’s and reviewers’ permission, the authors want to change the title of paper because of ...

Comment: Generally speaking, communications in academia don't need "formal sentences".  Just explain what you want to do, clearly and concisely.

Comment: @NateEldredge An excellent suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the peer-review process, you modify the manuscript until the editor accepts it (who in turn consults the reviewers for their opinion as needed).
This applies to the entire manuscript, including the title.
The latter may very well change due to the reviewers’ recommendations, in particular terminology is often changed in my experience.

Thus, explicitly asking the editor-in-chief for permission to change your title seems overkill to me.
You don’t have to do it for the same reason that you do not have to ask for explicit permission for every other change of the manuscript.

That being said, a change in the title can easily be overseen, even if a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) is employed.
Therefore I would recommend to simply mention the change of the title where appropriate in your resubmission, but without being overly submissive, e.g., like this:

> Please note that we changed the manuscript’s title to […], because […]
>
> We followed the reviewer’s suggestion and now speak of *gorgleflorps* instead of *florplegorgs* whenever appropriate, including the title.

Comment: Excuse me can I ask you to explain more about two words gorgleflorps  and florplegorgs? Thanks

Comment: @user0410: They are arbitrary words to represent some terminology, whose actual nature is not important for this example. I might as well have used *numbers* and *digits, species* and *clades,* or *graphs* and *networks.*

Answer (score 1):

What you write seems fine. Until very late in the process, the title should, in my view, be tentative. It should best express what the paper says. Especially if recommended revisions have changed that, or your view of it, by all means change it and just let the editor know.

If you get pushback, or refusal, from an editor, you can deal with it then. But, IMO, it would be improper to refuse.